# 401 Authentication credential missing or incorrect using Twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter4j

I am using `twitter4j` API for an Android app. I have given the Consumer key and the Consumer secret.

What can be the reason for this error? 
Is there any example code for android for twitter4j?

> Logcat Error:

```
01-20 09:23:26.719: ERROR/!!! Error-->(565): 401:Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect.
01-20 09:23:26.719: WARN/System.err(565): 401:Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect.
01-20 09:23:26.719: WARN/System.err(565): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[fde06384-e892de6e], statusCode=401, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.10}
01-20 09:23:26.719: WARN/System.err(565):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:310)
01-20 09:23:26.738: WARN/System.err(565):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:72)
01-20 09:23:26.738: WARN/System.err(565):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:94)
01-20 09:23:26.748: WARN/System.err(565):     at twitter4j.Twitter.verifyCredentials(Twitter.java:1394)
01-20 09:23:26.748: WARN/System.err(565):     at twitter4j.Twitter.getId(Twitter.java:212)
01-20 09:23:26.748: WARN/System.err(565):     at twitter4j.AsyncTwitter.getId(AsyncTwitter.java:128)
01-20 09:23:26.748: WARN/System.err(565):     at com.cabot.android.twittertest.MainTwitter.OAuthLogin(MainTwitter.java:121)
01-20 09:23:26.748: WARN/System.err(565):     at com.cabot.android.twittertest.MainTwitter.onClick(MainTwitter.java:89)
01-20 09:23:26.766: WARN/System.err(565):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-20 09:23:26.766: WARN/System.err(565):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-20 09:23:26.766: WARN/System.err(565):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-20 09:23:26.766: WARN/System.err(565):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-20 09:23:26.766: WARN/System.err(565):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-20 09:23:26.766: WARN/System.err(565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
01-20 09:23:26.781: WARN/System.err(565):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 09:23:26.781: WARN/System.err(565):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-20 09:23:26.781: WARN/System.err(565):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-20 09:23:26.781: WARN/System.err(565):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-20 09:23:26.781: WARN/System.err(565):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 09:23:29.487: DEBUG/dalvikvm(60): GC_CONCURRENT freed 937K, 46% free 4276K/7879K, external 1865K/3065K, paused 9ms+8ms
```

Code:

```
void OAuthLogin() {
    try {
        AsyncTwitter ATObj=new AsyncTwitter(username,password, this); 
        Twitter twitter=new Twitter();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET_KEY);
        RequestToken twitterRequestToken= twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
        String token = twitterRequestToken.getToken();
        String tokenSecret = twitterRequestToken.getTokenSecret();
        AFobj.getBasicAuthorizationInstance (username,password);
        int UserId=ATObj.getId();
        ResponseList<UserList> AllUserList=twitter.getAllUserLists(UserId); 
        String URI=UserId+"";
        Toast Display1=Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), URI, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Display1.show();
        String test="TEST01";
        Toast Display=Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Display.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("  !!! Error-->", ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I have tidied up your question. Next time please use the code indention function for code and the block-quote for a single log line.

Comment: thanks..have any idea on this bug?

Comment: @rahul now do u have solution of this problem ?

Comment: I have tried using http://sugree.com/project/twitter-android-sdk ...and as @Yusuke Yamamoto said basic auth is not supported now

Comment: Please add any valid Callback URL,then it will work,its works for me.and please check your access Permission also.

Answer (score 1):

The above code won't compile since AsyncTwitter doesn't implement getBasicAuthorizationInstance.
http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/AsyncTwitter.html

Additionally, basic auth is not supported anymore.
You need to acquire access token to invoke methods that require authentication.

Comment: I have gone through your code submit in https://github.com/yusuke/sign-in-with-twitter    But I want to use the twitter account to login another application through my android phone!